# show today's closed tickets in Trac wiki using ticketquery

Tags: trac

I would like to show using Ticketquery all closed tickets for the day only.  I have the following query
'[[TicketQuery(status=closed,owner=rrwithro|dmorales|hcpatel|pwmitche|adboatne|dbadmin,group=owner,order=priority,format=table,col=id|summary|priority|changetime)]]'

Whenever i put in changetime i get an integer error "".

Answer (score 2):

You want to see tickets closed *today* only, right? Then limiting the changetime should work with the following syntax:
`[[TicketQuery(status=closed,owner=rrwithro|dmorales|hcpatel|pwmitche|adboatne|dbadmin,group=owner,changetime=today;now,order=priority,format=table,col=id|summary|priority|changetime)]]`

**But** this is [for Trac0.12 only](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracQuery?version=20), sorry.

> Since 0.12, the date fields `created` and `modified` can be constrained by using the `=` operator and specifying a value containing two dates separated by a semicolon (';').

This has been [changed later](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracQuery?action=diff&version=26&old_version=25) to "two dates separated by two dots ('..')"

Answer (score 0):

That macro works fine in my Trac (after changing the user names, of course).  What version of Trac are you running?

Does the Trac log show anything useful?  If not, try increasing the log level to 'DEBUG' and see if any details get printed out.

Disable some or all of your Trac plugins and see if the behavior changes.  It is possible that the error might be originating from one of them.

Also, does that query work in the normal ticket query interface (not the macro)?  If so, you can save the query there and refer to it by number.

Comment: I am running v0.11dev-r6843, I know there is a v0.12 but dont know when the app owner will get a chance to upgrade.  Are you using v0.12?

Comment: Yes, I'm running 0.12.  The fact that you're running a development version and not an official release may also have something to do with it.  Do you have admin access to the Trac server?

Comment: v0.11dev-r6843 means even before the proper 0.11 release. You should really upgrade at least to v0.11.8 (lowest risk of plugin incompatibilities etc.), but certainly 0.12.5 (current old-stable) would help you much more.